# How to slide group of divs in html/css page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website where I need to slide a group of `div`s from right to left.

[This is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB8eA.jpg) 
I want to slide these divs from left to right in a circular way ie when div A  is on the left end and about to disappear it must be shown from right side

Comment: This is call `Content Carousel`, Google it before asking

Comment: `...slide a group of divs from right to left` then you say `...slide these divs from left to right` - at least be clear in your questions

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments this is called a Content carousel. For this you can use slick slider for example, its free to use and easy to setup, its also very well documented in my opinion. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ Heres the link 
(See the second example for what you want).